# Rails - Editing item from list by bootstrap modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new in Rails. I try to make a list of groups (`/groups`) where I want to have edit and delete option in each row. Editing should be implemented by modal because Group has only one attribute - `name`. So I don't want to open `/groups/number/edit`.

My problem is: I don't know how to bind chosen group with `form_for`. Maybe it isn't good approach indeed.
Modal is displayed, but the name field is blank. When I used debug for `@group` is blank too. I don't know why.

Here is my code(single group row):

```
<li id="group-<%= group.id %>" class="list-group-item">
<span class="group-name"><%= group.name %></span>

<%= link_to edit_group_path(group.id), "data-toggle" => "modal", "data-target" => "#myModal", :class => "edit-option btn" do %>
    <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-2x" ></i>
<% end %>
<%= link_to group, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Na pewno chcesz usunąć tę grupę?" }, :class => "delete-option btn btn-danger" do %>
    <i class="fa fa-trash-o" > usuń</i>
<% end %>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Zmień nazwę grupy</h4>
            </div>
            <%= form_for(@group) do |f| %>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <%= debug @group %>
                    <p>
                        <%= f.label :name, "Nazwa" %>
                        <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control'%>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Anuluj</button>
                    <%= f.submit "Zapisz zmiany", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
                </div>
            <% end %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller

```
def edit
@group = current_user.groups.find_by(id: params[:id])
end

def update
 @group = current_user.groups.find_by(id: params[:id])
 if @group.update_attributes(group_params)
   flash[:success] = "Nazwa grupy została zmieniona"
   redirect_to groups_path
 else
   redirect_to groups_path
 end
end
```

Comment: It seems, that group with given id has not been found. Try to use `Group.find(params[:id])` - it will throw an exception in such case.

Comment: I don't know how it works exactly, but params[:id] is related with method GET, yes? So it should find the id by /groups/id/edit. But in this situation there is no /groups/id/edit, because I want to have edit option on my index site (in modal).

Comment: `GET /groups/:id/edit` redirects to action edit of groups controller passing params[:id]. This action is used for editing already existing groups. In your case either the group with given id not exist at all or does not belong to current_user and this is the reason, that @group is nil.

Comment: Hmm... I'm sure I have an Idea of what you are trying to achieve. One question though: Is your code above repeated in a `@groups.each do` looping?

Comment: No. This code is a partial _group, which is rendering via list (<%= render @groups %>. I thought Rails knows from it which edit button was clicked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will assume that the answer to my question above is a yes, and so, I'll just continue to answer.

First thing: You don't want to be repeating different Modals for each group, you want only a single Modal to be used by all the groups.

Second thing: You are very correct with the idea of wanting to send the `group.id` to the edit method in your controller, for it to return that group back into your Modal

However, what is wrong is how you are trying to achieve this.

```
<%= link_to edit_group_path(group.id), "data-toggle" => "modal", "data-target" => "#myModal", :class => "edit-option btn" do %>
```

You are telling your link to do two things when clicked: (1) `go to edit path` (2) `open modal`. Which one will take more importance? Right now, it is the modal that is opening, and not the edit path working, which means that you are not getting to the controller at all, so accounting for why your `@group` is blank.

To achieve this, you will have to tell your link to do only one thing, and when that is successful, do the other.

What I'll advice is to use Ajax (by setting `remote: true`) on your link to go to the controller, and then open the modal on response.

Here is a breakdown of the steps:

1.Set `remote: true` to make the call with Ajax

```
<%= link_to edit_group_path(group.id), remote: true %>
```

2.Tell controller action (in this case, the `edit` action) to respond to `js`

```
def edit
  @group = current_user.groups.find_by(id: params[:id])
  format.js
end
```

3. Prepare an `edit.js.erb` file to handle the response (this will be in the same directory which your other view files are)
4. Populate the form with the `@group` from inside the response
5. Put the populated form in the modal
6. Use Javascript to show the modal

   ```
   $('.modal-title').html("Edit Group")
   $('.modal-body').html("<%= escape_javascript( render partial: 'form', locals: {group: @group} ) %>")

   $('#myModal').modal()
   ```

As simple and as direct as that. Hope this helps a lot.

Comment: Thanks for your engagement, I'm trying to programme it, but I think I don't understand exactly this approach. What correctly should I do in step3? And what do you mean by "populate the form with the @group"? I've never seen .js.erb file before. And I don't know javascript to much. Could you explain little more?

Comment: Great, almost done. format.js doesn't work for me. I had to use respond_to do |format|

Comment: respond_to do |format| // format.js // end. But still I have a little problem. After these changes it seems form_for doesn't see that must use PATCH method, to update. Do you know what can I do with it? (error: No route matches [PATCH] "/groups"). I have resources :groups in routes.rb

Comment: is the form modal getting the groups now?

Comment: what exactly is the error shown? asking for missing id or what?

Comment: Error is exactly "No route matches [PATCH] "/groups"" and there is a list of my all routes. I based on "resources :groups" and the problem I think is that: When I clicked button in modal I'm still in /groups route, and form_for is searching for PATCH method, but in routes there is no PATCH method for /groups. But I don't know how to resolve it.

Comment: so, what is the route that it should have gone to?

Comment: Normally in RESTful application is it /groups/id, which is connected with PATCH. But I'm not sure if in this case should be the same, because in this approach I haven't /groups/id view. I'm a bit confuse, it's my firs rails application sorry.

Comment: Can you  close this if it has solved your original problem, and open another question for your new task? Thank you